# diff: How to use another diff algorithm

Tags: diff

Not `git diff`, just plain `diff` or an equivalent tool: How to diff files using another diff algorithm, like histogram? I'm tired of seeing unrelated curly braces being matched up.

I tried `diff --minimal`, but it wasn't noticeably better for the differences I'm looking at.

This turns up nothing:

```
diff --help | grep -i histogram
man 1 diff | grep -i histogram
```

Is there a better diff tool or method for diffing files?

Comment: You can try `diffstat`

Comment: I think the standard `diff` command doesn't implement different algorithm. You can slightly tweak the standard one, but not to the degree that `git diff` allows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tool does a curly braces aware diff. It takes some time to run but the result is accurate : [I-Compare](https://i-compare.web.app)

Comment: It doesn't seem curly brace aware to me, but nice that you can paste text into it. I've wanted that.